# Picasa without G +

Tags: google-plus, picasa-web-albums

Is there a way to use Picasa Web albums without having to use/share it on Google Plus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use Picasa Web Albums without Google+.

Currently what happens is that when you try to go to Picasa Web Albums, you are redirected to Google+ Photos, but there you are given an option to go back to Picasa Web Albums:

[image]

Clicking on the [link takes you here](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1).

You can directly bookmark this link to directly goto Picasa Web Albums each time.