# Is there a way to share photos in Google+ with people who do not have a Google+ account?

Tags: google-plus, photo-sharing

I want to share photos with family and friends who do not necessarily have Google+ accounts.

In Picasa I could save photos as Private so they just needed the Private Link.

But I don't see that option in Google+.

Comment: This is addressed indirectly by [using Picasa with Google+](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59669/picasa-without-g).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When viewing a Google+ album, click on "shared X" and you will get a lightbox where you can either directly enter email addresses of those without G+ accounts. They will get emails to view the album. Or you can use a direct link.

[image]

Comment: Please update the instructions:   Click *Share Privately* right below the Album title.

Comment: @ClayNichols I put "shared X" because it could be multiple different values.